# Cannot enable Standard Object Permissions for Guest User in Public Access Settings

Tags: permissions, force.com-sites, guest-user

I'm trying to enable Create and Read permissions on Accounts for the Guest user with a [Salesforce Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide.meta/salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide/sites_setup_overview.htm) on a scratch org. When I go to Sites in Setup,

1. click on the site
2. click Public Access Settings
3. scroll down to Standard Object Permissions

The Read and Create checkboxes for Accounts  are unchecked but there's no apparent way to change them. What needs to be done to enable the Read and Create permissions here?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: is that screen shot after you've clicked `edit` at the very top of the profile?

Comment: Thank you @KrisGoncalves! You can post the answer if you feel so inclined :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your screenshot, it doesn't look like you clicked the `edit` button at the top of the profile.

Once you go into your Site Details and click `Public Access Settings`, you'll be redirected to the Guest User Profile for that Site. You need to then click Edit to change the permissions/settings before scrolling down.

[image]

Now the boxes should be selectable and you'll notice some help text related to Standard Object Permissions display as well.

[image]